# How to get all clickable elements in a webpage

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to know what are all the elements in a webpage that are clickable irrespective of added via anchor elements, onclick, addeventlistner. Is there a way to get them?

I was trying to use the following for collecting but some times it blocks the page

- EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener
- HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener
- Element.prototype.addEventListener
- HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.addEventListener

The above prototypes have been extended to meet the requirement. It should be working for any js framework

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for. Everything in a web page is clickable. Maybe you are looking for registered event listeners?

Comment: I am looking for registered event listeners and also the elements which has onclick attributes, added click events via javascript and so on

Comment: "Clickable" here obviously means "clicking it _does something_" (whether that's navigation, firing off an event handler, or whatever).